# What are the letters and numbers next to an opening's name on online services?

Tags: opening, online-chess

Here, it shows "C22": [Name of opening]. This is from an online service, and I was confused what this is. At first, I thought it was for the specific sites database, but I have seen the letters and numbers used with the opening name on chess.stackexchange.com too. What is it?

[image: Letter, Number, Opening]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Encyclopedia of Chess Openings (or ECO) is a classification system for the opening moves in chess.

Instead of the traditional names for the openings, ECO has developed a coding system that has also been adopted by other chess publications. There are five main categories, "A" to "E", each of which is divided into 100 subcategories.

Here is more info and related questions in case you are interested:

[How are the ECO codes for chess openings assigned?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/how-are-the-eco-codes-for-chess-openings-assigned)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_of_Chess_Openings

[Does ECO openings classification have an established more detailed specification - by sub indexes?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/does-eco-openings-classification-have-an-established-more-detailed-specification)

And this is the exact same code that you mentioned, covered in another source:

https://www.365chess.com/eco/C22_Centre_game_Berger_variation